How to view a list of Recent files when right-clicking the Taskbar icon in Windows
After I installed Blender 4.2.2LTS (all ok) I dragged the exe to the MS Windows Taskbar to create a shortcut. If I click it, it starts Blender normally (with the cube/camera in a starter project). I then work on and save a project. So all's well so far.
The problem:  In past blender versions, if blender was closed, and I right-clicked on the taskbar icon to start it, I'd see a list of my previously saved projects to choose from. And I could then click one to open that project directly in Blender, bypassing the "new project" layout.
This is not happening in 4.2  I do not see the Recent files list when I right click -- I expect it to be the same list of Recent files that I see in the Recent Files list displayed in the opening splash screen when blender opens a new project.
Did the ability for Blender to display Recent files in the Windows taskbar icon right-click go away in 4.22LTS? If not, how do I get that functionality back so I can see the list of Recent files if I right-click the Blender icon in the Windows taskbar?
Thanks!

What Windows version are you using? - I still have the right-click Recent Files list here with Blender 4.2.3 under Windows 10. Is your version of Blender registered to open Blend files via Edit > Preferences > System > Operating System Settings > Register?

Win11.
Blender registered to open Blend files via Edit? -- yes.

Just FYI -- Worked fine in 3.8. Only in new 4.2.2 LTS install it does not display recent files. I also looked at the prefs in 3.8, compared with new 4.2.2, seems to be the same as far as I can tell.
Could it be that I still have 3.8 on the same machine as a separate install?  I don't/can't really delete the older blender version as I still need to open and work on some older projects using that older blender version -- and that 3.8 icon works fine to see the available recent files when I right click it in the task bar.
Problem is only in 4.2.2LTS

I have 5 versions installed here right back to 2.83. Every time I installed a later version it automatically became the default when double-clicking a Blend file and the Recent Files list was available from the right-click taskbar menu, including with 4.2.3.

I'm glad it is working for you.
Is there anything I can / should be looking at, or checking, to try to make it work for me too? coz its not.
As I mentioned, my previous 2.8 version displays the recent files when right clicking the taskbar Icon linked to the 2.8 blender version, but the 4.2.2 taskbar icon does not display the list when I right click that versions taskbar icon.

I can't think of any way to force it to behave offhand. I've never seen that problem before. I assume double-clicking on a blend file is launching it correctly? If so, the registry entry should be correct but that's clutching at straws!

"double-clicking on a blend file is launching it correctly?"  Yes.

Sounds like a Windows problem in that case. Search Google for 'taskbar jump lists not showing'. There are lots of links there.
